# Background image quality

Tags: android, nine-patch

I want to apply a background image to a linear layout and I have problems because the image loose from quality when stretched.

The image is composed by the fill color and some dots pattern applied over the background.
[image]

The image was made with Adobe Illustrator (png). Also I tried using nine-patch but does not work, the dots are  stretched.

Should I make this background from code(override onDraw from the linear layout)?

Comment: What size of image did you use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to repeat that pattern, not stretch it. Create a `drawable resource` in `xml` form, representing your tiled background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    android:src="@drawable/background_image"
/>
```

Comment: here you go , that's it, since you are using simple image you can repeat it as above ,if you use some complex image u will need to use images of different size in different res folders

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't know I have such a wonderful possibility by using a simple drawable.